# Not sure what is causing the error "Tuple index out of range"

Tags: python

I am trying to answer this question: Create a function cubefit(xdata, ydata) (arguments in that order) that returns a numpy array of the best fit* parameters [A, B, C, D] that fit the list xdata of  x  values to the list ydata of  y values, to a cubic equation of the form  y= Ax^3  + B x^2  + C x  + D

*where the fit is determined using a non-linear least-squares regression test (the default fit method of scipy's curve_fit() function)

This is my attempt:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as scpo
```

```
   def cubefit(xdata,ydata):
       x = np.array(xdata)
       y = np.array(ydata)
    
       def cubic(x_a,A,B,C,D):
           return A*x_a**3+B*x_a**2+C*x_a+D
       actual_fit_parameters = scpo.curve_fit(cubic, x , y)
    
       fit_D = actual_fit_parameters[3]
       fit_C = actual_fit_parameters[2]
       fit_B = actual_fit_parameters[1]
       fit_A = actual_fit_parameters[0]
    
       return [fit_A,fit_B,fit_C,fit_D]
```

I get this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-fafc77be7ebf> in <module>()
      3 import numpy as np
      4 assert "cubefit" in dir(), "It appears that you may not have defined a function named `cubefit`, or you may not have executed your answer cell."
----> 5 assert type(cubefit([0,1,2,3],[0,1,8,27])) != None, "It appears that your function `cubefit` does not return anything"
      6 assert type(cubefit([0,1,2,3],[0,1,8,27])) != list, "It appears that your function `tophat` does not return a list"
      7 assert type(cubefit([0,1,2,3],[0,1,8,27])) == np.ndarray, "It appears that your function `tophat` does not return a numpy array"

<ipython-input-39-d4f3443da67b> in cubefit(xdata, ydata)
     11     actual_fit_parameters = scpo.curve_fit(cubic, x , y)
     12 
---> 13     fit_D = actual_fit_parameters[3]
     14     fit_C = actual_fit_parameters[2]
     15     fit_B = actual_fit_parameters[1]

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: `curve_fit()` returns a *tuple with two arrays*. Please do [read the documentation for functions you use](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html), it includes example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit()` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html), you'll see what is happening:

> **Returns**
>
> - `popt`: array
>
>   Optimal values for the parameters so that the sum of the squared residuals of `f(xdata, *popt) - ydata` is minimized.
> - `pcov`: 2-D array
>
>   The estimated covariance of `popt`. The diagonals provide the variance of the parameter estimate. To compute one standard deviation errors on the parameters use `perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))`. [...]

The function returns **two** results, both arrays. When you look further down, in the examples section, you see how the authors think you should use the function:

> ```
> popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
> # ...
> ```

They use tuple assignment to split out the two arrays into two variables.

Your code doesn't, it treats the 2-value tuple as if it is an array with at least 4 values. I'm *guessing* that you wanted the first array, so you could use:

```
actual_fit_parameters, _ = scpo.curve_fit(cubic, x , y)
```

to assign the second array, `pcov`, to `_` (indicating you want to ignore it in your code).

You didn't include sample input or an *expected* output, so I can't tell you if my guess here is going to work out for you.

Some other notes:

- `type(someobject) != None` is **always true**. `type(None)` returns `NoneType`. If you need to test that something other than `None` was returned, use `someobject is not None`.
- Don't use `type(someobject) == SomeType` or `type(someobject) != SomeType`, you should use [`isinstance(someobject, SomeType)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to do type checks. `isinstance()` also returns true for subclasses. (In the rare event that you must test for *one specific type only* and not for subclasses, use identity tests, `type(someobject) is SomeType`).